# add a column from a dataset to another dataset in R

Tags: r, merge, dataset

Suppose i have two dataset

ds1

```
NO   ID      DOB         ID2   count
1   4083    2007-10-01  3625    5
2   4408    2008-07-01  3603    2
3   4514    2007-07-01  3077    3
4   4396    2008-05-01  3413    5
5   4222    2003-12-01  3341    1
```

ds2

```
loc  share
12    445
23    4
10    56
1     1
23    34
```

I want "share" column of ds2 to be added to ds1 so that it would look like

dsmerged

```
NO    ID      DOB         ID2   count   share
1   4083    2007-10-01  3625    5      445
2   4408    2008-07-01  3603    2      4
3   4514    2007-07-01  3077    3      56
4   4396    2008-05-01  3413    5      1
5   4222    2003-12-01  3341    1      34
```

i tried merge as
dsmerged <- merge(ds1[,c(1:5)],ds2[,c(2)])

But what it does is it duplicates the dataset (5*5=25 rows) while it does add "share" column. i dont want that duplicate values obviously. Thank you

Comment: Don't you have a key to merge by? It seems that the "NO" and "loc" should be your key? And if you just want to add the share column and the order doesn't matter, than you can simply do `ds1$share <- ds2$share` , which I think is very unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the rows represent the same id then you can just cbind

```
ds3 <- cbind(ds1, share = ds2$share)
```

but it would be better if you had an id to join on.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_cols(ds1, ds2['share'])
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
setDT(ds1)[, share := ds2[["share"]]]
```